# Magento configurable product page price not reducing after deselecting a option

Tags: javascript, php, magento, configuration

After deselecting an option checkbox on  a configurable product page the value doesn't vanish and price still remain same as when the checkbox was selected.

The only option I got was to refresh the page to see the updated value.

Any thoughts on the same are highly appreciated?

Comment: You can do it by custom code  or use extension.For details visit this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/change-product-image-for-configurable-products

Comment: no Mahmood I think I need not to go for an extension for this issue.It may be solved either by editing bundle.js or by editing radio.phtml.But how to edit and where to change,I don't know right now as I am new to magento

Comment: this is not easy job to do it easily.Download the extension and see how this work.And implement the same thing in your project.

Comment: Did you check to see if you have an JavaScript error usning Firebug or chrome console

Comment: yes I checked.I also got solution.onClick="bundle.reload.reloadPrice()" worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is an bundle object in javascript.
You can modify (deselect in this case) the selected options in there like so:

First edit radio.phtml and add a data attribute to the "none / deselect" radio button. Like so:

```
data-option="<?php echo $_option->getId(); ?>"
```

Then somewhere in your custom js script in the event listener add the following:

```
var option_id = $(this).data('option');
bundle.config.selected[option_id] = [];
bundle.reloadPrice();
```

Now after clicking on that radio button the price will change accordingly.